# Hover with variables, show next/closest/corresponding div

Tags: jquery

**Basically what I want is when I hover over test to show ddd, when I hover over test2 show ddd2.**

But right now when I hover over test2 it's showing ddd instead of ddd2.

```
    <div class="ugh">
    <div class="test">test</div>
</div>

    <div class="a">a</div>
<div class="f">    <div class="b">b</div></div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
<div class="dang">
    <div class="ddd">ddd</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="ugh">
    <div class="test">test2</div>
</div>



<div class="dang">
    <div class="ddd">ddd2</div>
</div>
```

Sorry about the messy css

```
    $('.test').hover(mouseIn,mouseOut);

    function mouseIn() {
        var menuName = $('.ddd:first').show();
          //.....
    }
    function mouseOut() {
        var menuName = $('.ddd:first').hide();
          //.....
    }

var menuName = $('.ddd').hide();
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/423/)**

Comment: Your class names are really unhelpful. Try using something semantic, especially when you are asking for people to help out.

Comment: Please check given answer it will help you to reach your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/427/).  This JS will work for you.

```
$('.ddd').hide();
$('.test').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.dang').filter(':first').find('.ddd').show();
});
$('.test').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.dang').filter(':first').find('.ddd').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `data-*` attribute to specify which element to show (which should have an id).

For example...

**HTML (trimmed for example)**

```
<div class="ugh">
    <div class="test" data-target="#ddd">test</div>
</div>

<div class="dang">
    <div id="ddd" class="ddd">ddd</div>
</div>

<div class="ugh">
    <div class="test" data-target="#ddd2">test2</div>
</div>

<div class="dang">
    <div id="ddd2" class="ddd">ddd2</div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.test').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);

function mouseIn() {
    var menuName = $($(this).data("target")).show();
}

function mouseOut() {
    var menuName = $('.ddd').hide();
}

var menuName = $('.ddd').hide();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5mC2y/)

Comment: hummm, I don't think I can use the data attribute solution since it requires a unique data-target name

Comment: @Newbie: It's only the `id` attributes that need to be unique, you can have duplicate `data-target` values. Although your example suggests you only have one `dang` per `test` anyway

Answer (score 1):

Working Example

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/430/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#pp").hide();
 $("#kk").hide();    
 $("#t1_id").hover(
  function() {
    $("#pp").toggle();    
});
$("#t2_id").hover(
  function() {
    $("#kk").toggle();    
});
});
```